# Mysql query search a string in all columns of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder how I can mount a SQL as portable as possible to query for all columns of a table for a specific phrase, like:

**Table**

```
ID | Name           | text      | Date       | Author  | Status
1  | Augusto Weiand | Test text | 2010-01-01 | Deividi | 1
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE columns LIKE '%augusto%2010%text%"
```

I did not put enough detail, excuse me, I like to make a dynamic SQL, where I do not need to specify the columns with 'AND' or 'OR', as it is possible to do in Postgres:

```
Select * 
From table 
Where table::text ~~ '%augusto%2010%text%'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "portable"?

Comment: To many MySQL versions

Comment: If that date field has a char or varchar datatype, you are being unwise.  If it has a date or datetime datatype, it has to be excluded from this attempt.

Comment: No problem, it was an unfortunate example, say that all fields are text or varchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you would concatenate the values in dynamic SQL:

```
set @Pattern = '%augusto%';

select @q := concat('select * from Table1 ',
                   'where concat(', group_concat(column_name), ', "") like "', @Pattern, '"'
                   )
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = 'Table1';

prepare st from @q;
execute st;

deallocate prepare st;
```

Of course, dynamic SQL is not particularly portable.  The idea would work in most databases.  The code would look different.

Tested and working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9cf3/30).

And finally, you can do this with variable substitution (which is the better approach):

```
select @q := concat('select * from Table1 ',
                   'where concat(', group_concat(column_name), ', "") like ?'
                   )
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = 'Table1';

set @p = '%augusto%';

prepare st from @q;
execute st using @p;

deallocate prepare st;
```

Also tested (;-).

Comment: I test the script but doesn't works.... :( here is a link test, but thanks for replies!:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9cf3/1

Answer (score 3):

It's doable, although I ***strongly*** suggest you look into full-text search for efficiency;

To avoid looking for all patterns in all fields one by one, you can just concat and search in that;

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(name,'|',text,'|',date,'|',author,'|',status) txt
      FROM Table1) a
WHERE txt LIKE '%augusto%'
  AND txt LIKE '%2010%'
  AND txt LIKE '%text%';
```

Note that *no indexing will help you here*, since you're searching in a calculated column. On the other hand, since you're searching with a leading wildcard `%searchterm`, you won't get much help from indexes even if searching field by field :)

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8929/5).

Comment: Thanks, but I did make a more dynamic SQL, like the example in postgres... :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   Select * FROM table WHERE text LIKE "%text%"
                          OR date LIKE "%2010%"
                          OR Name LIKE "%augusto%"
```

if you want them all together then use AND

```
   Select * FROM table WHERE text LIKE "%text%"
                          AND date LIKE "%2010%"
                          AND Name LIKE "%augusto%"
```

Comment: I think OR is replaced by AND

Comment: Thanks, but I did make a more dynamic SQL, like the example in postgres... :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this store procedure to search a text in all column in table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_FindStringInTable @stringToFind VARCHAR(100), 
@schema 
sysname, @table sysname 
AS

BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + 
@table + '] WHERE ' 

SELECT @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''' + 
@stringToFind + ''' OR '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
AND TABLE_NAME = @table 
AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar')

SET @sqlCommand = left(@sqlCommand,len(@sqlCommand)-3)
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
PRINT @sqlCommand
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
PRINT 'There was an error. Check to make sure object exists.'
PRINT error_message()
END CATCH
```

Execute it like this

```
EXEC sp_FindStringInTable '%searchword%','schema_name', 'tablename'
```