# Look for one value in multiple Columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to search one value in multiple columns of my table.
Im making

`SELECT* FROM myTableName WHERE'value' IN(column1, column2, column3);`

This is working for me, but i wan't to make it with LIKE. Something like this:

`SELECT* FROM myTableName LIKE '%value%' IN(column1, column2, column3);`

Because i'm making a browser, so i need to use the LIKE.

I'm getting error and i don´t know how can i make it well.

Anyone knows something?

Comment: One LIKE per column is needed. But I'd rather ask myself why there are 3 columns to be searched. Design issue?

Comment: Use `WHERE CONCAT_WS(@delimiter, column1, column2, column3) LIKE '%value%'` where `@delimiter` is a char which not exists in columns values (for example, `CHAR(0)`). This is equal to `WHERE column1 LIKE '%value%' OR column2 LIKE '%value%' OR column3 LIKE '%value%'`, but is slower then separate testing.

Answer (score 1):

With PostgreSQL there is the [ANY or ALL form](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-subquery.html#AEN16718):

```
WHERE col LIKE ANY( subselect )
```

or

```
WHERE col LIKE ALL( subselect )
```

where the subselect returns exactly one column of data.

Comment: But OP has _3 columns_ in his _MySQL_ table. How could OP use this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `OR` with `LIKE` instead of `IN` with `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM myTableName 
WHERE 
    column1 LIKE '%value%'
OR
    column2 LIKE '%value%'
OR
    column3 LIKE '%value%'
```

**NOTE**:

I will store `column1,column2,column3` in one column if you need to search it because one column with only one `LIKE` will be higher performance than you used multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select @q := concat('select * from Table1 ',
                   'where concat(', group_concat(column_name), ', "") like ?'
                   )
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = 'Table1';

set @p = '%augusto%';

prepare st from @q;
execute st using @p;

deallocate prepare st;
```

Ref:[Mysql query search a string in all columns of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898055/mysql-query-search-a-string-in-all-columns-of-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can use three like patterns with `or`:

```
WHERE column1 LIKE '%value%' OR
      column2 LIKE '%value%' OR
      column3 LIKE '%value%'
```

However, that is cumbersome because you have to repeat the pattern multiple times.  There is a work-around that works in more recent versions of MySQL:

```
where exists (select 1
              from (select t.column1 as val union all
                    select t.column2 as val union all
                    select t.column3 as val
                   ) x
              where x.val like '%value%'
             )
```

This does not work in older versions of MySQL because the double nested correlation is not supported.

([Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45a894307c2458c692ad9c4bd8410f12) is an example.)